# How do I find values of a constant for which a list of vectors are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\color{purple}{\text{Question}}$$

Given a list of vectors ${(1,0,3,1),(0,-2,2,1),(2,-2, a(a-2),3)}$ are there values for a for which this list is linearly dependent? If so what are they?

$$\color{purple}{------------------------------}$$

**I have found one, from inspection**

$$2(1,0,3,1)+(0,-2,2,1)=(2,-2, 8,3)\implies a(a-2)=8$$

But how can I find all the values of $a$ for when this list is linearly dependent? And this only came true cause I was able to catch it with my eye, what if the list is not so obvious, so in that case too this is a very ineffective method.

So I thought maybe if I put these columns as a matrix and do RREF, then it would seem clearly and this is what I got:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -2-6+a(a-2)\\ 0 & 0 & 0 &  \end{bmatrix}$$

Still it is not clear. I dont know what to do.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172669/for-what-value-of-h-the-set-is-linearly-dependent and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386073/for-which-values-of-a-do-the-following-vectors-for-a-linearly-dependent-set-in and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713592/what-values-of-a-is-the-set-of-vectors-linearly-dependent and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946169/for-which-values-of-k-are-the-following-vectors-linearly-dependent and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250375/for-which-value-of-k-will-the-vector-be-a-combination-of-two-vectors

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector are linearly dependent iff the matrix with the vector as column has rank less 3. So you can find the values of $a$ such that the matrix has not maximal rank.

Comment: u mean $-2-6+a(a-6)=0)$ ?

Comment: Yes, you need to find the values of $a$ such that the third vector is a linear combination of the others: so the values of $a$ that satysfies the equation you write above.